# Magento Paid user registration for Customer Group

Tags: magento, registration

I have different types of Customer group (General, School, Publisher, Corporate). Customer select our Customer group on registration page from frontend.

But I need charge some amount ($100) when customer register as Publisher.

Please give any suggestion that how to implement.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to change? Price for a product? or registration fee? 
Please be more specific about your requirements.

Comment: I want Registration Fee. 

http://gobookkart.com/customer/account/create/

Please check above link. 

I have created four types group (General, School, Publisher and Corporate). When customer select Publisher, I want registration fee ($40). Only for Publisher.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to charge a particular customer group for registration,
Rough flow will be as follows :

1. Catch an event at the <**customer_register_success**> observer.
2. Fetch Customer Model from observer event data.
3. Inspect if the customer's group belongs to "Publisher"
4. If it's Publisher, redirect them to checkout, you may provide payment option for this.
5. If the publisher is successful at payment, you need to remove pending status from his registration
6. Return to registration success page.

---

Notes.

1. You need to create virtual product for registration fee.
2. You need to create a pending step similar to confirmation email before the target customer group user activation